# Fill Two Arrays on the fly From stdin File in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I wrote a bash script that reads a file from stdin $1, and needs to read that file line by line within a loop, and based on a condition statement in each iteration, each line tested from the file will feed into one of two new arrays lets say named GOOD array and BAD array. Lastly, I'll display the total elements of each array.

```
#!/bin/bash

      for x in $(cat $1); do
        #testing something on x
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          #add the current value of x into array called GOOD
        else
          #add the current value of x into array called BAD
        fi
      done

      echo "Total GOOD elements: ${#GOOD[@]}"
      echo "Total BAD elements: ${#BAD[@]}"
```

What changes should i make to accomplish it?

Comment: `for x in $(cat ...anything...)` is an antipattern. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for best-practices around iterating over file contents.

Comment: Your question sounds like, "Please do my homework for me." To improve your question, include what the output is, what you've tried, and what specifically you're trying to fix.

Comment: While I've answered this, I do agree that it's not currently the kind of question we strive for here. An ideal question would be more narrow -- say, "how do I append to an array in bash?" (though that one's a duplicate) or "why does reading from a file with `for word in $(cat $1)` expand globs when I don't want it to?" (though that one's *also* a duplicate); with the shortest code necessary to illustrate that single, specific, narrow question.

Comment: Thx @CharlesDuffy for your help, it is appreciated. Arrays in bash is a bit ambiguous to me, i already watched 3 courses for bash scripting before i asked that question. Pardon me for asking the question, but it is my first time and I'll improve it from now on.

Comment: @MoatazOsama : Your script does not process the input line by line, but word by word. Also, I don't understand what the `[ $? ... ]` is supposed to do. `$?` is the status code of the most recently executed command.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# here, we're checking the number of lines more than 5 characters long
# replace with your real test
testMyLine() { (( ${#1} > 5 )); }

good=( ); bad=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if testMyLine "$line"; then
    good+=( "$line" )
  else
    bad+=( "$line" )
  fi
done <"$1"

echo "Read ${#good[@]} good and ${#bad[@]} bad lines"
```

Note:

- We're using a `while read` loop to iterate over file contents. This doesn't need to read more than one line into memory at a time (so it won't run out of RAM even with really big files), and it doesn't have unwanted side effects like changing a line containing `*` to a list of files in the current directory.
- We aren't using `$?`. `if foo; then` is a much better way to branch on the exit status of `foo` than `foo; if [ $? = 0 ]; then` -- in particular, this avoids depending on the value of `$?` not being changed between when you assign it and when you need it; and it marks `foo` as "checked", to avoid exiting via `set -e` or triggering an ERR trap when your boolean returns false.
- The use of lower-case variable names is intentional. All-uppercase names are used for shell-builtin variables and names with special meaning to the operating system -- and since defining a regular shell variable overwrites any environment variable with the same name, this convention applies to both types. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html